# 3D development in C#

Tags: c#, frameworks, 3d

I want to revisit some of the 3D work (using VRML97-Java) I did back in the late 1990s, eventually, I would like to develop applications for the forthcoming [LEAP Motion](http://www.leapmotion.com) controller so I would like to have an environment-building technology in which to play.

Can anyone recommend an easy-to-use, *high-level* (I am emphatically **not** a mathematician) framework for C# or Java that I could use to do this? Googling and reading around on SO have so far led me to Unity3D, MS XNA, SDL.NET and AutoCAD, but I'm not sure which would be the most suitable for RAD and prototyping. Of course if a modern VRML/X3d technology is available I would probably prefer to use that, but it would appear that [both are dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668821/whatever-happened-to-vrml/3671313#3671313).

Any pointers would be very gratefully received.

Comment: Unity is a good framework for doing prototyping in as it has a full featured and high level API and developer environment. Be warned that at least  with the free version of unity, you can only write code within the environment they provide, so you're unlikely to be able to access LEAP's API.

Comment: Thanks v. much for the tip. You can't just add libraries to a Unity project in C# then?

Comment: @5arx - Actually you can. The scripting is C# and compiled by Mono. You can also use UnityScript ( ECMAScript-inspired syntax ) or C# within their IDE which is based on MonoDevelop.  All this was easily researched.

Comment: Thanks. I meant in the free version that @yiding mentioned.

I take your point re: researching, but why start from scratch when the community is full of people who have first-hand knowledge that they can share?

Comment: I believe the free version doesn't let you extend it with _native_ libraries, which might be needed if you are interfacing with fancy hardware. I'm not sure though, I haven't played with it for a few months.

Comment: ok thanks very much. I'll d/load the free version and have a play with it.